# Solve for the coefficients of (functions of) the independent variable in a symbolic equation

Tags: octave, symbolic-math

Using Octave's [symbolic](https://octave.sourceforge.io/symbolic/index.html) package, I define a symbolic function of t like this:

```
>> syms a b c d t real;
>> f = poly2sym([a b c], t) + d * exp(t)
f = (sym)

     2                t
  a⋅t  + b⋅t + c + d⋅ℯ
```

I also have another function with known coefficients:

```
>> g = poly2sym([2 3 5], t) + 7 * exp(t)
g = (sym)

     2            t
  2⋅t  + 3⋅t + 7⋅ℯ  + 5
```

I would like to solve `f == g` for the coefficients `a, b, c, d` such that the equation holds for all values of `t`. That is, I simply want to *equate the coefficients* of `t^2` in both equations, and the coefficients of `exp(t)`, etc. I am looking for this solution:

```
a = 2
b = 3
c = 5
d = 7
```

When I try to solve the equation using `solve`, this is what I get:

```
>> solve(f == g, a, b, c, d)
ans = (sym)

                t      2            t
  -b⋅t - c - d⋅ℯ  + 2⋅t  + 3⋅t + 7⋅ℯ  + 5
  ───────────────────────────────────────
                      2
                     t
```

It solves for `a` in terms of `b, c, d, t`. This is understandable since in essence there is no difference between the variables `b, c` and `t`. But I was wondering if there was a method to somehow separate the *terms* (using their symbolic form w. r. t. the variable `t`) and solve the resulting *system of linear equations* on `a, b, c, d`.

---

**Note:** The function I wrote here is a minimal example. What I am really trying to do is to solve a *linear ordinary differential equation* using the method of *undetermined coefficients*. For example, I define something like `y = a*exp(-t) + b*t*exp(-t)`, and solve for `diff(y, t, t) + diff(y,t) + y == t*exp(-t)`. But I believe solving the problem with simpler functions will lead me to the right direction.

Comment: For anyone else that needs to do a similar thing: Octave is not the right tool for this task. There are computer algebra systems such as Maxima that are specialized for doing symbolic math. Use them instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a terribly slow and dirty method to get the job done. The coefficients have to be linear in `a, b, ...` though.

The idea is to follow these steps:

- Write the equation in `f - g` form (which equals zero)
- Use `expand()` to separate the terms
- Use `children()` to get the terms in the equation as a symbolic vector
- Now that we have the terms in a vector, we can find those that are the same function of t and add their coefficients together. The way I checked this was by checking if the division of two terms had `t` as a symbolic variable
- For each term, find other terms with the same function of `t`, add all these coefficients together, save the obtained equation in a vector
- Pass the vector of created equations to `solve()`

This code solves the equation I wrote in the note at the end of my question:

```
pkg load symbolic

syms t a b real;
y = a * exp(-t) + b * t * exp(-t);

lhs = diff(y, t, t) + diff(y, t) + y;
rhs = t * exp(-t);

expr = expand(lhs - rhs);
chd = children(expr);
used = false(size(chd));

equations = [];

for z = 1:length(chd)
  if used(z)
    continue
  endif
  
  coefficients = 0;
  
  for zz = z + 1:length(chd)
    if used(zz)
      continue
    endif
    division = chd(zz) / chd(z);
    vars = findsymbols(division);
    if sum(has(vars, t)) == 0 # division result has no t
      used(zz) = true;
      coefficients += division;
    endif
  endfor
  coefficients += 1; # for chd(z)
  
  vars = findsymbols(chd(z));
  nott = vars(!has(vars, t));
  if length(nott)
    coefficients *= nott;
  endif
  
  equations = [equations, expand(coefficients)];
endfor

solution = solve(equations == 0);
```